# Edit response with template TRIVIA

Tags: actions-on-google

I try Trivia App with templates, but I want to know how to modify the answers that say: Yes, it's a good answer! Let's move on to the next question "
Thank-you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are prompts provided by the templates. These have been designed by VUI experts to create a fun conversational experience.

We don't provide a way to customize those VUI prompts.

For the trivia template there are other persona's that you can pick. Each of these have their own prompts that are appropriate for that persona.